# Return map() object as a beautiful soup iterable

Tags: python, web-scraping, lambda, beautifulsoup

I am trying to iterate through downloaded HTML code using the Beautiful Soup library to extract a specific elements text. The specific element I aim to grab requires a nested for loop to ensure I am getting the right one.

Here is the current code:

```
elist = []
if package.find('div', class_='kernel'):
    for g in package.find_all('div', class_='kernel'):
        for h in g.find_all('pre', class_='screen'):
            elist.extend(h.find('code', class_='literal'))
```

My question is, is it possible to shorten this code using the map() function (possibly even turning it into a one-liner)?

I have tried something like this:

```
elist1 = list(map(lambda x: x if package.find('div', class_='kernel') else None, package.find_all('div', class_='kernel')))
```

but I need to iterate over the returned value `elist1` using the Beautiful Soup `find_all` method in order to extract the correct element.

Is there any way to return a map() object as a Beautiful Soup iterable class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector:

```py
elist = package.select("div.kernel pre.screen code.literal")
```

This returns empty `ResultSet` if, for example, `<div class="kernel">` doesn't exist.

Comment: This returns the text along with its outer HTML tag ```<code class=literal>desired text</code>```, is there any way to just return the inner text?

Comment: @Maslin use `.text` or `.get_text()` method.

Comment: .text and .get_text() won’t work on a list, but iterating on it with map returned the desired list.